# Python pandas Two columns the index and region. The region has the state and then below it towns. I need a new column that shows corresponding state

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
def get_list_of_university_towns():
with open('university_towns.txt', 'r') as f:
data = (line.rstrip() for line in f)
lines = list(line for line in data if line)
thing = [lines]     

indexx = [lines.index(line) for line in lines if '[edit]' in line]
numlist = [indexx]
wow = pd.DataFrame(thing)
tr = wow.T
tr.columns=['Region']
```

When I return the code it returns:

```
"""    Region
0   Alabama[edit]
1   Auburn (Auburn University)[1]
2   Florence (University of North Alabama)
3   Jacksonville (Jacksonville State University)[2]
4   Livingston (University of West Alabama)[2]
5   Montevallo (University of Montevallo)[2]
6   Troy (Troy University)[2]
7   Tuscaloosa (University of Alabama, Stillman Co...
8   Tuskegee (Tuskegee University)[5]
9   Alaska[edit]
10  Fairbanks (University of Alaska Fairbanks)[2]
11  Arizona[edit]
12  Flagstaff (Northern Arizona University)[6]
13  Tempe (Arizona State University)
14  Tucson (University of Arizona)
15  Arkansas[edit]
16  Arkadelphia (Henderson State University, Ouach...
```

How do I get it so that I can make a new column named the state that appends the state name with the corresponding index of the state? The index portion works in returning the corresponding index to all of the states.
I essentially want it to return:

```
    Region    State
1   Auburn    Alabama
2   Florence  Alabama    etc..
```

Comment: What does your data look like? Please paste a few lines of data so that it's easier to understand what you are looking for.

Comment: How do you intend to know that Tuskegee (Tuskegee University)[5] falls in Alabama?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to iterate over the lines, and use an if-else to determine whether the line is a state or a region. The states appear all to have the `[edit]` tag in them, so any line with that must be a state, otherwise it's a region.

To create the dataframe itself, we can create a list of tuples, with the first element being the state, and the second being the region (after appropriately cleaning the text). Then pass the list to pandas, which will elegantly convert it into a dataframe.

A potential solution (though I'm not sure exactly what your text file looks like):

```
data = []
for line in lines:
    if '[edit]' in line:
        state = line.replace('[edit]', '')
    else:
        region = line.split(' (')[0]
        data.append((state, region))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['state', 'region'])
```